# external table retain data where?【green plum db】

Tags: greenplum

when I query to the external table that `LOCATION` is hdfs,

I don't make sense that where dose greenplum retain data(including tmp & cashdata used for process).

is that any rule to hold data in greenplum?

for instance

1.a lot of data : gp's hdd

2.little data : gp's memory

3.No,do not retain in gp at all. gp is just display them.

4.etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data from external tables is only hold in memory, not stored on disk (except temporarily if swapping is required). If you want to store data permanently, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO <internal table> SELECT * FROM <external table>;
```

And future queries can use "internal table" to speed up performance.